# Someone has your password: Gmail does not send SMTP mail from another location

Tags: email, smtp, gmail

In my program I send an email from a specific Gmail account using their SMTP. It works fine when I send the mail from my own machine or a machine that is located in an office nearby.

One of our customers have their server machine in another city. When they try to run the program, their email is not delivered. When I login to Gmail, I see a "*Someone has your password!*" mail and it looks suspicious to Gmail.

I have also done the following things:

1. I have opened `587` in all the machines that run my program in their firewall settings.
2. I have enabled the *"Never show an alert for unusual activity."* option via Gmail's *Details* section in the inbox page (bottom right side). This was more than a week ago.
3. I have allowed access for less secure apps.

How can I let Gmail know that it can basically allow activities from anywhere?

Answer (score 3):

From https://support.google.com/a/answer/33330?hl=en

> Each Gmail account is intended and designed for use by an individual
>   user. If you have multiple users frequently accessing the same account
>   from various locations, you may reach a Gmail threshold and your
>   account will be temporarily locked down.

What you can do is like suggested a group

edit: You could try relaying SMTP. Google supports that and you can approve Server on an IP Basis.
(https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491)

Comment: I understand if Google blocks emails when it reaches the threshold. I think it is currently 500 emails/day. My problem is not the number of emails. It's accessing from different locations. Is there a way we allow access from different locations as long as we do not send more than their limit?

Comment: You can try relaying. You have to approve the server by ip to relay messages through google: https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491

Comment: Does this require a Gmail For Work account?

Comment: Ok, this I don't think will be much helpful. I guess Gmail is not the right tool to use in this situation. I'm gonna try our Office365 that seems to be able to send SMTP mails from different locations. Thanks for you help anyway.